# RFC 7230 field-value syntax is weird

Tags: google-chrome, http

From [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230.html#appendix-B), following syntax are defined:

```
field-value = *( field-content / obs-fold )
field-content = field-vchar [ 1*( SP / HTAB ) field-vchar ]
field-vchar = VCHAR / obs-text
```

`VCHAR` is just ASCII 21 to 7F, and `obs-text` is ASCII 80 to FF. So `field-vchar` is merely ASCII 21 to FF, which doesn't contain space or htab.
So `field-content` is something like 'a' or 'a a' (quote not included), and `field-value` is merely a repetition of `field-value` (I ignored `obs-fold` because it is not relevent in this question).

Then it means 'a ab bc c' is valid `field-value` but 'a b c d' is not.
Isn't this weird? Why would anyone want this kind of syntax?

Even more, request messages which google chrome sends contains a header field like following:

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

'Mac OS X 10', which has spaces on both side of 'X', is invalid syntax for `field-value`.

Am I missing something? Or google chrome is not strictly conforming HTTP 1.1?

Comment: See [Errata 4189](https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata/eid4189)

Comment: And https://github.com/httpwg/http-core/issues/19 and RFC 9110.